# Crash after fast typing in TextChanging event

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Try this:

```
<TextBox TextChanging="TextBox_OnTextChanging"></TextBox>

private void TextBox_OnTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    sender.Text = "some string"; // It does not matter about string
}
```

If you try to change text after `TextChanging` event it is going to freeze or [crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6XHy.jpg) while you **type fast** (I mean pressing random keys by all fingers) in textbox.

It is ok with TextBox_OnTextChanged event.

(Where this problem came from? I am trying to create NumericTextBox based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186357/using-uwp-textbox-textchanging-to-ignore-wrong-data) and this Q is core problem.)

Edit: Crash is this unhandled exception:
[image: Crash]

Comment: When you say "crash", describe in detail what you mean.

Comment: To me it looks like that code would throw a `StackOverflowException`, since you keep setting the text again whenever it is about to change.

Comment: @ Visual Vincent this is not the case. If pressing slowly, it is fine. Changing text in OnTextChanging method does not call event again.

Comment: @hatchet : updated by screenshot

Comment: @Alamakanambra - that tells you there is an exception, but it doesn't tell you what the exception is. That's the info we need to see.

Comment: @hatchet yeah... It does not tell me what the exception is - thats the problem. That one line of code should not be the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Visual Vincent, the `TextChanging` event occurs when the `Text` property already reflects the new value, but still not be rendered in the UI. When you type fast, it might cause potentially fatal errors that can lead to a crash. By my side it froze but the debugger didn't crash.

> It does not tell me what the exception is - thats the problem. That one line of code should not be the problem.

It is possible your VS is configured to debug only managed exceptions. If you get a native exception, this may appear. You can find the `Debug` options in your project's property and change the `Debugger type` from `Managed only` to `Mixed(Managed and Native)`:

[image]

And I think you already knew why it crashes, how to solve the problem, maybe you also want to get the information when it crashes without showing error message, for this problem, you may refer to [How to debug a program when it crashes w/out exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792456/how-to-debug-a-program-when-it-crashes-w-out-exception).